# ApacheDS OID Specifying Data Type List

Tags: java, ldap, apacheds, ldif

I am using ApacheDS as an LDAP Server. When you define attributes there are different types. For example, String or boolean. Is there a way to specify a List. So a List of Mobile?

If not, how can this be done. I am aware there is an ObjectClass called groupOfUnquieNames. But the problem is that I have multiple List. So for example, List of Mobile and List of Address.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no list type, but attributes default to being multi-valued - `mobile` for example is multi-valued:

```
dn: uid=user,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
...
mobile: 000-000-0000
mobile: 111-111-1111
```

In other words user `user` has two mobile numbers. Both would be returned in a search request.

Comment: ok, what about if I would like to keep them unique? It could mean that I have a distinguished name and add the distinguished name. So for example, one user works at one company.

Comment: This was just an example. Suppose an Address has address, city, postcode. I want to link this specific Address to a user. That's why a distinguished name is better. I have two list. One for Mobile and one for Address. I really don't want to repeat several address, city, postcode as multivalued. Any better ideas?